# Best Differential Equation, Partial Differential Equation and Calculus of Variations books?

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations

Electrical Engineer here thinking of switching to physics. What are the best  Differential Equation, Partial Differential Equation and Calculus of Variations books?
Ideally they explain the topic thoroughly (by a physicist's standard), provide examples, and the problems are based on real world problems. Only list one book for each.

Comment: What's your level of math knowledge?

Comment: Then my recommendations are ODEs = Boyce/ DiPrima, PDEs=Strauss, CoV=Gelfand/ Fomin or Weinstock.

Comment: Sorry I didn't I presed enter and the comment was submited, here is my full list: Engineer: Trig, Calculus 1,2,3, Differential Equations ( Note that I want to go more In depth), Undergraduate: Numerical Methods,  Set Theory, Combinatorics, Set Theory, Algebraic Structures, Group Theory, Linear Algebra, Abstract Algebra, Real Analysis 1 ( in my Uni it was the first of 3 undergraduate real analysis courses), and Discrete Mathematics and Cryptography ( I was originally CompSci).

Comment: Ah.  Well then my answers change a bit.  ODEs=Arnold, PDEs = Strauss will still probably be good.  You could try Sommerfeld instead if you like or if your analysis class was good enough you might be able to handle Evans, CoV=Jost/ Li-Jost.

Comment: No problem. :-)

Comment: for Calculus of Variations I prefer [The Variational Principles of Mechanics - Cornelius Lanczos](https://books.google.co.in/books/about/The_Variational_Principles_of_Mechanics.html?id=ZWoYYr8wk2IC) and [Goldstein](https://books.google.co.in/books/about/Classical_Mechanics.html?id=Spy6xHWFJIEC) not sure if these for good for mathematicians though

Answer (score 0):

This might be a partial answer but what level of mathematics are you looking for? At a beginners level, I would suggest Elementary Differential Equations and Boundary Value Problems by Boyce & DiPrima for DE's and a Feynaman Lecture (I think the one on Principle of Least Action) and a few chapters of Calculus of Variations and Optimal Control Theory by Liberzon for CalcVars.

Comment: At the level of a PHD physics Student.